# Minimum correlation for worthwhile regression analysis

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, r-squared

For a university project, I would like to regress (X) % of a countries alternative energy production against (Y) environmental health outcomes. I plan to add controls next.

After producing a scatterplot, I have a pearson correlation .234 @ .05 significance- No clear trend can be seen by eye.

When running a bivariate regression an R^2 of .045 is achieved.

When plotting a quadratic line as opposed to a linear an R^2 of .07 is achieved.

Is there a minimum correlation that one would like to see before conducting further analysis?

Comment: Have you tried to look at the residual plots QQ plots or residuals? They may be useful to decide between quadratic and linear regression. I do not see why you couldn't continue as long as you report how meaningful the correlation is and not just that it is significant. Further, the decision for the appropriate model (linear vs quadratic) might be sample-dependent as it is ambiguous. I would therefore be careful when interpreting the results.

Comment: Pearson correlations only capture linear association. If the "trend" is nonlinear, that association will be missed. You don't say how many observations are in your data. Based on the plots, it looks fairly substantial. Why not rank order each variable and create ventile (20) buckets? By taking a within bucket average, the resulting scatterplots will uncover any local, nonlinear structure in the relationships.

Answer (score 2):

It is not that surprising that you don't see a trend in a scatter plot when the correlation is .2. Below is a graph of randomly generated data with different levels of correlation. In the social sciences correlations between 0 and .3 (corresponding to and $R^2$ range of $0^2=0$ till $.3^2=.09$) are pretty much the norm for individual level data. Having the figure below in mind, as a benchmark, can help the interpretation of your scatter plots.

[image]

Macro level data tend to be more correlated, as everything changes with the economic cycle or increases over time...

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what your research question is. If you trying to prove a relationship between countries alternative energy production and environmental health outcomes then even low correlation (low effect) could be statistically significant in predicting environmental health. Especially since environmental health is likely to be 'noisy', i.e. there are many many factors to consider.

On the other hand if you are trying to asses the most important (highest effect) factors in determine environmental health you may want to look at more that just alternative energy production given at low values of $R^2$ the variance in environmental health is not being explained well.